# Nested SELECT with multiple JOINS

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have trouble writing a SQL statement which will join multiple columns and add on them another select.

I have:

```
TableA       | TableB      | TableC
idA          | idB         | idC
state        | idA         | idB  
             | created_time|
```

And I want to find all rows where state=CLOSED and created_time is the newest.

So I managed to write these 2 queries:

```
SELECT TableA, TableB, TableC 
FROM TableB
JOIN TableA ON TableB.idA = TableA.id
JOIN TableC ON TableB.id = TableC.idB
WHERE TableA.state = 'CLOSED';
```

And another query which should find the newest Date:

```
SELECT t.id, t.created_time, t.idA
FROM TableB t
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT id, idA,  MAX(created_time) AS MaxDate
     FROM TableB
     GROUP BY id) tm ON t.id = tm.id AND t.created_time = tm.MaxDate
```

But I have no clue how to concatenate these queries and make SET(state="OPEN") on them.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 2):

I think `DISTINCT ON` does what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.id) . . .
FROM TableA a JOIN
     TableB b
     ON b.idA = a.id JOIN
     TableC c
     ON b.id = c.idB
WHERE a.state = 'CLOSED'
ORDER BY a.id
```